# Create Trigger MySql update or insert in another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to learn more about triggers in mysql, so bear with me.
I have two tables,

`TestTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ItemId INTEGER, Date date, Value REAL)`

`TestTable2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ItemId INTEGER,
Year INTEGER, Month INTEGER, Open REAL, Close REAL, Increase REAL)`
`

Where the table TestTable is measurements on a certain item on a specific date.
TestTable2 contains measurements for a specific month,year and the increase during this period.

I want to create a trigger which updates or insert values into TestTable2 as I insert values into TestTable.

This is what the trigger i tried to create looked like,

`CREATE TRIGGER 'monthUpdateTrigger' AFTER INSERT ON TestTable 
BEGIN 
IF NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TestTable2 WHERE (ItemId=NEW.ItemId AND Year=YEAR(NEW.Date) AND Month=MONTH(NEW.Date)))) THEN 
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (ItemId,Year,Month,Open,Close,Increase ) VALUES (NEW.ItemId , YEAR(NEW.Date), MONTH(NEW.Date),NEW.Value,NEW.Close,0.0); 
ELSE
UPDATE TestTable2 SET Close=NEW.Close AND Increase=(NEW.Close/(SELECT Open FROM TestTable WHERE (Year=YEAR(NEW.Date) and Month=MONTH(NEW.Date))) WHERE (Year=YEAR(NEW.Date) and Month=MONTH(NEW.Date))
END IF;
END;`

But this does not seem to work, I get the error,

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN IF NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TestTable WHERE (ItemId=NEW.ItemId AND Yea' at line 1`

Can someone please point out the error/errors. Or offer a better solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: remove `(` and  move it to `IF NOT EXISTS (`.

Comment: I still get the same error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TestTable2 WHERE (ItemId=NEW.ItemId AND Year' at line 1`

Comment: Can you please format your code so that it's a bit more readable. Then you might spot it yourself.